# Android Library различия -source и -javadocs артефактов

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, javadoc

Написал библиотеку, выложил в jcenter, подцепил и заметил алерт который меня напрягает:

[image: алерт]

Ни в одной библиотеке, которую я использовал до этого не было такого алерта, следовательно - я где-то накосячил в таске формирования -source и -javadocs артефактов.

Может кто сталкивался с этим до меня?

Скрипт формирования артефактов:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def javadocTask = task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }

    javadocTask.dependsOn variant.javaCompile

    def jarJavadocTask = task("jar${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Jar) {
        description "Generate Javadoc Jar for $variant.name"
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from javadocTask.destinationDir
    }

    jarJavadocTask.dependsOn javadocTask
    artifacts.add('archives', jarJavadocTask)

    def jarSourceTask = task("jar${variant.name.capitalize()}Sources", type: Jar) {
        description "Generates Java Sources for $variant.name."
        classifier = 'sources'
        from variant.javaCompile.source
    }

    jarSourceTask.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    artifacts.add('archives', jarSourceTask)
}
```

Сама библиотека: https://bintray.com/ztrap-llc/maven/FormattedEditText/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался (правда не без пары вырванных клоков волос). Косяк действительно допустил я. Но узнать в каком именно месте, мне не удалось, т.к. на просторе *GitHub'ов* я позаимствовал скрипт, который (О, чудо!) идеально отработал.

Ниже сам скрипт:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.compile
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```